# Reusable objects that change when one is changed in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, template

I've been designing websites in Illustrator for quite a while and the major problem I found when doing so is that I have to repeat some elements into all my documents. For instance, I would like to design my header and footer on a template so that every time I create a new page they're already in the document. Additionally and most importantly, if I edit the header and footer template, all the pages using them will automatically update.

Is there any way to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, in fact two ways:

1. place the document inside your other document. This will link the files so once you change things on disk, then illustrator prompts for an update.
2. use symbols. In the CC verson symbols can also update trough the cloud, but not local disk.

Comment: thanks for your answer joojaa. I haven't tried it yet but it makes sense it's like placing an image that updates as you edit it. I'll try it out as soon as I can and let you know how it went.